# How can I map out multiple images in Gatsby with GraphiQl?

Tags: graphql, mapping, gatsby, gatsby-image, graphiql

I would like to query multiple images from a specific folder on a webpage via GraphiQl.

I've tried it multiple ways, but I'm not able to display the images. I can however get 1 image to show (without mapping), but not multiple.

I can also display the id or base of the image on the webpage, to show a list of all of them. But if I try it with the actual images I get the following error message in the console:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `alt` is marked as required in `J`, but its value is `undefined`.
    at J (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image/dist/index.browser-4e524ce6.js:615:13)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image/dist/index.browser-4e524ce6.js:635:13)
    at MainImage
    at G (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image/dist/index.browser-4e524ce6.js:608:13)
```

The page however is showing correctly, but without the images. Is there something going wrong in my code?

```
import * as React from "react"
import {graphql} from "gatsby"
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
import Layout from "../../components/layout"

const JewelryPage = ({ data }) => {
  const image = getImage(data.allFile.childrenImageSharp)
  return (
    <Layout pageTitle="Jewelry">
        <h1>Jewelry</h1>
      {data.allFile.edges.map(image => (
         <GatsbyImage image={image} />
      ))}
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default JewelryPage

export const query = graphql `
query {
   allFile(filter: {relativeDirectory: {eq: "content/portfolio/jewelry"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        childrenImageSharp {
          gatsbyImageData(
            width: 800
            placeholder: DOMINANT_COLOR
            formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
          )
        }
        base
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
`
```

My gatsby-config looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: ``,
    siteUrl: ``
  },
  plugins: [{
    resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-google-analytics',
    options: {
      "trackingId": ""
    }
  }, "gatsby-plugin-image", "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet", "gatsby-plugin-sitemap", {
    resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
    options: {
      "icon": `${__dirname}/src/images/icon.png`
    }
  }, "gatsby-plugin-mdx", "gatsby-plugin-sharp", "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
  {
    resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
    options: {
      "name": "images",
      "path": `${__dirname}/src/images/`
    }
  },
  {
    resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
    options: {
      "name": "pages",
      "path": `${__dirname}/src/pages/`
    }
  },
  {
    resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
    options: {
      "name": "jewelry",
      "path": `${__dirname}/src/images/content/portfolio/jewelry/`
    }
  },
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
    options: {
      fonts: [
        `Cormorant\:200,300,300i,400,500,600`,
        `Forum\:200,400,500,600`
      ],
      display: 'swap'
    }
  },
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify",
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const JewelryPage = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Layout pageTitle="Jewelry">
        <h1>Jewelry</h1>
      {data.allFile.edges.node.map(image => {
       console.log("image", image);
       return <GatsbyImage image={image?.childrenImageSharp?.gatsbyImageData} alt="some alt text"/>
      })}
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

`image` in your loop, stands for `node`, so in order to provide to `GatsbyImage` the correct data you must access each specific position of `childrenImageSharp` and `gatsbyImageData`.

In addition, as the error prompts, `alt` attribute is required as a property of `GatsbyImage`, you must provide it for each image.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

I've tried this before, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

I get the following error:
Error in function eval in ./src/pages/portfolio/jewelry.js:12
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'gatsbyImageData')

`
  10 |         <h1>Jewelry</h1>
  11 |       {data.allFile.edges.map(image => (
> 12 |          <GatsbyImage image={image.childrenImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} alt="some alt text"/>
     |                                                      ^
  13 |       ))}
  14 |     </Layout>
  15 |   )
`

Comment: What's the `console.log()` of `image` inside the loop?

Comment: It's strange, but now, running the same code as above, the editor says that "image" is never defined in the code (it's even greyed out in SVC). Even though it's defined, and was working before. 

So the page crashes completely now, and I won't be able to console.log().

The message I get:

Unknown Runtime Error

can't access property "gatsbyImageData", image.childrenImageSharp is undefined

Comment: Sorry, that was legacy code from copy-pasting your source code. You don't need `image` at that level along with `getImage` because you are accessing each `gatsbyImageData` at `image.childrenImageSharp.gatsbyImageData`. I've updated the snippet

Comment: Thank you. It's not yet working on my side.

The console.log() shows the following for the image:
image 
Object
node:
base: "earrings-on-travertin-product-photography-among-creatives-5.jpg"
childrenImageSharp: [{…}]
id: "55b1d2ee-23e2-5814-9121-46c8ca472bd0"
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object

And Gatsby itself shows this:
Error in function eval in ./src/pages/portfolio/jewelry.js:12
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'gatsbyImageData')

Any thoughts?

Comment: `image?.childrenImageSharp?.gatsbyImageData` Try this. It seems that there's no image node in some of your images

Comment: If I do this, nothing is shown. No images on the page, but neither an error message nor log in the console.

Comment: I've pushed it to Github, it might help. It's on this page: https://amongcreatives.netlify.app/jewelry/

Github: https://github.com/bartfluitsma/amongcreatives

Comment: `data.allFile.edges.node.map` change the loop to that

Comment: Yes, I've tried that before. It gives me this error on page load:

Error in function JewelryPage in ./src/pages/jewelry.js:10
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: The issue seems to be related to your data source then :/ If you `console.log(data)`. Does it come undefined at some point?

Comment: Yes, if I console log data I get: **Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined**

I'm trying to recreate a new gatsby project just for the sake of importing images, let's see if I'm able to work that out. It's strange, because with one image if works fine.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with the data I'm using, or the link towards it. I've set up a new gatsby environment, and it works fine. Not quite sure yet where that goes wrong, but I can continue :) Thanks again for your help!

I'm using the following now:
        {data.allFile.edges.map(image => (
            <div key={image.node.id}>
              <GatsbyImage image={image.node.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} 
              alt={image.node.base.split('-').join(' ').split('.')[0]}
              />
            </div>